# nodejs mongodb async.Each done

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How to detect when async.Each is done loop all objects/arrays loaded into the parameters. how to call the ALL FINISH log.

```
db.collection('tests').find(query).limit(10).toArray(function(err, db_results) { 
    console.log("count: "+db_results.length);

    async.each(db_results, function (db_resultsx, cb) {
        db_resultsx._id = db_resultsx._id.toString();
        db_resultsx.xdate_visited = moment(db_resultsx.date_visited).format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");
        documents.push(db_resultsx);

    }, function(documents) {
          console.log(documents);
          console.log(documents.length);
          console.log("ALL FINISH");
          process.exit();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason that the `async.each` function is not finishing is that the callback isn't being called within the second function.  I've created a snipped with a simple example without the mongo call but with a timeout instead.

If you look at the docs https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each the second argument is a callback (in your code this is the value `cb`) that needs to be called to signify the end of the code you are running.

```js
function delayedReturn(callback) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('timeout complete');
    callback(false, ['first value']);
  }, 1000);
}
var documents = [];
delayedReturn(function(err, db_results) { 

    async.each(db_results, function (dbResult, cb) {
        
        documents.push(dbResult);
        console.log('documents pushed', dbResult)
        cb();

    }, function(error) {
        if(error)
        {
          console.error(error);
        }
          
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/caolan/async/master/dist/async.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to use `async.each()` given that the code that it should be running isn't asynchronous.

Instead, you can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
db.collection("tests").find(query).limit(10).toArray(function(err, db_results) {
  console.log("count: " + db_results.length);

  let documents = db_results.map(function(db_resultsx) {
    db_resultsx._id = db_resultsx._id.toString();
    db_resultsx.xdate_visited = moment(db_resultsx.date_visited).format(
      "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"
    );
    return db_resultsx;
  });

  console.log(documents);
  console.log(documents.length);

  curl(URL, { data : documents }, function(err) {
    console.log("ALL FINISH");
    process.exit();
  });
});
```

Comment: I didnt specify, I do a curl after it finishes looping each, to send the new documents over.

Comment: @Boy you mean you perform the curl after _all_ documents have been processed, or for each document separately?

Comment: after all documents have been processed

Comment: @Boy see my edit. I don't know how `curl` works specifically so I made a guess, but it's more meant to reflect the general idea of adding an additional asynchronous step to your process.